# Division Equation: returns NaN currently

Tags: javascript, html, css, equation

I have run into a problem with one of my javascript functions. I am trying to divide an integer by an integer and keep getting NaN as the result. I have read about and tried various possible solutions but have been unable to find the correct answer. Please have a look at the following code (load it up if you want) and let me know how I can fix it if you can. Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
*:focus {
outline: none;
}
@font-face {
font-family: systems_analysis;
src: url(systems_analysis.ttf);
}
@font-face {
font-family: eufont;
src: url('eufont.ttf');
}
.button {
background-color: white; 
color: black;
border-radius: 6px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 400px;
height: 20px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: systems_analysis;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1.5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
.button:hover {
background-color: black; 
color: white;
}
.button:active {
transform: translateY(1px);
}
.button:focus {
outline:0 !important;
}
.balanceBox {
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 40px;
border: 1px transparent;
text-align: center;
width: 400px; 
}
.priceBoxAltra {
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 40px;
border: 1px transparent;
text-align: center;
width: 225px;
}
.priceBoxBexa {
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 40px;
border: 1px transparent;
text-align: center;
width: 225px;
}
body {
background-image: url("risefx_background.jpg");
}
</style>
<head>
<title>RiseFX</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<span><input type="text" id="altraPrice" class="priceBoxAltra" value="1.00000"></span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span><input type="text" id="bexaPrice" class="priceBoxBexa" value="1.00000"></span>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<input type="text" id="fxPrice" class="priceBoxAltra" value="0.00000">
</center>
<br>
<center>
<span><input type="button" id="altraRoll" class="button" value="TRADE" onclick="altraFunction()"></span>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<span><input type="button" id="bexaRoll" class="button" value="TRADE" onclick="bexaFunction()"></span>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<input type="text" id="balance" class="balanceBox" value="1.0000000000" readonly>
</center>
<script>
    function altraFunction() {
             var altraRollVar = (Math.random()*2);

             document.getElementById("altraPrice").value = altraRollVar.toFixed(5);
             fxPriceConversion();

}
</script>
<script>
    function bexaFunction() {
             var bexaRollVar = (Math.random()*2);

             document.getElementById("bexaPrice").value = bexaRollVar.toFixed(5);
             fxPriceConversion();
}
</script>
<script>
    function fxPriceConversion() {
             var altraRollBoxVar = document.getElementById("altraRoll").value;
             var bexaRollBoxVar = document.getElementById("bexaRoll").value;
             var conversion = altraRollBoxVar / bexaRollBoxVar;

             document.getElementById("fxPrice").value = conversion.toFixed(5);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, please read about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is an awful lot of clutter here.

Second, your problem is pretty obvious. You've isolated the problem enough that you know it has to do with division. Your only division is in these lines:

```
var altraRollBoxVar = document.getElementById("altraRoll").value;
var bexaRollBoxVar = document.getElementById("bexaRoll").value;
var conversion = altraRollBoxVar / bexaRollBoxVar;
```

The value of `bexaRollBoxVar` is the value of the input with id `bexaRoll`. That value is `"TRADE"`. None of your code ever changes that. So, your third line above is dividing by a string, not an integer. Thus the error.

I should point out that you have the same problem with `altraRollBoxVar`. You're actually dividing a string by a string. Unsurprisingly, that doesn't work.

Even a minimal attempt at debugging this, such as `alert(bexaRollBoxVar);`, would have revealed the problem. In the future, please make an effort to solve the problem yourself before posting here.